# RuntimeError: Proxy error(ArgumentNullException) in aspose.pdf (python via .Net)

Tags: python-3.x, .net, linux, aspose, aspose.pdf

To convert pdf to HTML, I am using the aspose.pdf library. I have installed the library through `pip3 install aspose-pdf`. This library works fine for my Windows machine in Python, version 3.8 to 3.10.
But facing an:
error in linux machine: `RuntimeError: Proxy error(ArgumentNullException): Value cannot be null. (Parameter ‘key’)`
I have tried Centos, ubuntu, and RedHat, but getting the same error.
source code:

```
import aspose.pdf as pdf

doc = pdf.Document("input.pdf")
saveOptions = pdf.HtmlSaveOptions()
doc.save("output.html", saveOptions)
```

system details:

- os: Ubuntu 20.04, centos 7
- python version: 3.8, 3.9, 3.10
- aspose.pdf: 23.3.0 (python via . Net)

Note: all machines are newly installed
Thanks in advance

Comment: We noticed your similar inquiry in our official support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/t/runtimeerror-proxy-error-argumentnullexception-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-key/262653) and have responded there. You can please follow up there. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AsadAli "Oops! That page is private."

Comment: Can you please try to create a new post in the Aspose.PDF forum so that we can proceed  further to assist you accordingly.